# How to make all posts in a category sticky?

Tags: categories, sticky-post

Total WP and web development noob here.

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make all the posts in one of my categories into "stickied" posts. But so far I've had no luck.

What I've tried is this sexy little snippet of code:

```
<?php 
if (in_category('bestcategoryever')) {
stick_post(); }
?>
```

...but to no avail. Perhaps I'm not putting it in the right place (not quite sure where I should put it really) or perhaps it's wrong to start with.

Please explain thoroughly and plainly, my terminology in these things isn't the best.

I hope you can help me!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather need a `save_post` hook. Check following code it marks the post sticky for the specified if it is not already.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mark_post_sticky' );
function mark_post_sticky( $post_id ) {

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && !isset($_POST['sticky']) &&
        in_category('bestcategoryever',$post_id) ) {

        $_POST['sticky'] = 'sticky';        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it's not working. Where do I implement this? I tried the index.php but as I'm quite the novice to this type of stuff so I can't say quite what I'm doing wrong. It's very frustrating.

[This](http://surfarama.com/) is the theme that I'm using.

Comment: You need to paste it in functions.php in your theme.

Comment: Hey again! Quick question, what would I have to change in the code above to mark all posts in a category as 'not sticky'? Thanks again!

Comment: If you meant to restricting admin to not making post sticky of category. You would call `unset($_POST['sticky']);`. However if you want to make all posts sticky would have different solution. Please post a new question.

Comment: Maybe I can just edit my question and you can edit your answer? Because all I want is pretty much the same thing but instead of making all the posts of the category sticky it should make them "not sticky". So that if a post in that category is already sticky it will not be.

Comment: Or if that is not in the spirit of stackexchange, maybe you could just explain what part of your original code actually makes the post sticky? Is 'sticky' a value that is somehow defined in the WP core?

Comment: Let it be here for others. Start discussion in a new question

Comment: Done and done: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/how-to-make-all-posts-in-a-category-unsticky